# Is there any way we can lowerCase the string while using filter in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function in Haskell that takes a string and, after removing specific characters from it, returns a list of the characters in the string. Is there any way I can have the output be lowercase?

See my function below:

```
getList s = filter (\w -> w `notElem` [",.?!-:;\"\'",]) (words s)
```

Comment: you're not filtering out for the chars in the specific list but for words equal to `",.?!-:;\"\'"` (after removing the spurious comma).  Check my answer below for a working solution with lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your function is doing what you intent

you can rewrite is as

```
getList = map (map toLower . filter (`notElem` ",.?!-:;'\"")) . words
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, its perfect

Answer (score 1):

Use [`toLower :: Char -> Char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) from `Data.Char`:

```
lowerCase :: String -> String
lowerCase = map toLower
```

Just apply `getList` to `lowerCase s` instead of just `s`.

Comment: getList s = filter (\w -> w `notElem` [",.?!-:;\"\'",]) (words lowercase s)  like this

Comment: That should be `words (lowercase s)`, not `words lowercase s`. But yes.

Comment: getList s = filter (\w -> w `notElem` [",.?!-:;\"\'",]) words (lowercase s)

Comment: i get an error on this line "error: parse error on input ‘]’"

Comment: You added a comma in your list for no reason. Why are you writing new questions in comments? If you have a problem you can't solve on your own, ask another question elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @AJFarmar for your help.